# Would git ever affect MIDI drivers or other hardware?

Tags: git, macos, midi

Pretty crazy situation, but here goes. I gig in a band with two USB MIDI controllers plugged via direct USB (i.e., not MIDI DIN to USB) into my 2012 Macbook Pro, and running through Mainstage. I've been using this setup for around a year, and it's been fine through the upgrade to Mojave as well.

Yesterday I did a few hours of work on my Mainstage file, using the keyboards at my desk rather than the ones I use in my rig. Then I took the computer to my gig and all of a sudden the computer wouldn't recognize my gigging keyboards.

It recognized other MIDI devices plugged into it, but neither Mainstage nor Midipipe, a MIDI router/modifier program I sometimes use, saw that the keyboards were plugged in.

The keyboards would sometimes appear in MIDI Monitor (a program whose name says it all), and I could see that the keyboards were *receiving* messages from the computer (I wrote a MIDI plugin in Mainstage that causes various pads on the keyboards to light up, and they were lit up) Also, when opening Audio/MIDI setup, the keyboards appeared plugged in (they were lit up) but the second I did anything, played a note or anything, Audio/MIDI setup would crash.

Plugging all the same cables into my 2016 Macbook worked, thank god, and I finished the gig on my newer but slower backup computer.

Now, the **only thing** I could imagine that might have caused anything to be out of the ordinary, after the exact setup has worked for is this: I decided that morning to start using git to track changes to my Mainstage project. I used `git add .` on the folder containing my Mainstage file, and while that was perhaps not the best idea (it added something like 3200 files, probably because of subfolders and maybe because of package contents or something), it didn't give me any angry messages. (although all I've done is commits, I didn't branch or restore or anything else).

Is there any possibility that putting this folder in git messed up my computer's MIDI drivers? And only for these keyboards in particular?!?!?

Comment: It is not possible to affect the drivers themselves, but it might be possible to mess up Mainstage's configuration file(s). Anyway, this seems to be completely unrelated to git.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, do check the result of `git config core.autocrlf`: I would advice to set it to false, in order to make sure Git is not trying to normalize your eol (end olf line) characters of the files you are adding (changing CRLF to LF for instance)

Then grab a pristine copy of your files, and init/add them again to a new repo: they should be unchanged.